# Deserializing JSON into an object with Json.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm playing a little bit with the new [StackOverflow API](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/stack-overflow-api-private-beta-starts/). Unfortunately, my JSON is a bit weak, so I need some help.

I'm trying to deserialize this JSON of a User:

```
  {"user":{
    "user_id": 1,
    "user_type": "moderator",
    "creation_date": 1217514151,
    "display_name": "Jeff Atwood",
    ...
    "accept_rate": 100
  }}
```

into an object which I've decorated with `JsonProperty` attributes:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("user_id", Required = Required.Always)]        
    public virtual long UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("display_name", Required = Required.Always)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I get the following exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException:
> Required property 'user_id' not found
> in JSON.

Is this because the JSON object is an array? If so, how can I deserialize it to the one User object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have two objects in this JSON. The outer object has a single property `user` which contains the actual user object. Are you taking this into account in your code? I also don't see any JSON arrays here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As Alexandre Jasmin said in the comments of your question, the resulting JSON has a wrapper around the actual `User` object you're trying to deserialize.

A work-around would be having said wrapper class:

```
public class UserResults
{
    public User user { get; set; }
}
```

Then the deserialization will work:

```
using (var sr = new StringReader(json))
using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    var js = new JsonSerializer();
    var u = js.Deserialize<UserResults>(jr);
    Console.WriteLine(u.user.display_name);
}
```

There will be future metadata properties on this wrapper, e.g. response timestamp, so it's not a bad idea to use it!

Comment: Thank you very much, Jarrod, for the explanation, and the very great solution!

Answer (score 36):

If you don't want to create a wrapper class you can also access the User this way:

```
String jsonString = "{\"user\":{\"user_id\": 1, \"user_type\": \"moderat...";
JToken root = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
JToken user = root["user"];
User deserializedUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(user.ToString());
```

See [this page in the Json.NET doc](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializingJSONFragments.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks! Used to deserialize my array of objects `List<User> deserializedUsers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(users.ToString());`

Comment: Thanks! This led me to fixing my issue

Answer (score 5):

Similar to @Alexandre Jasmin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2555899/1037948), you can use an intermediary JsonSerializer to convert instead of the using the high-level `JsonConvert` on `.ToString()`.  No idea if it's any more efficient...

**References:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9453198/1037948
- http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing

**Example:**

```
var root = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
var expectedUserObject = serializer.Deserialize<User>(root["user"].CreateReader());
```