# JSON.NET deserialize part of JSON object as dictionary

Tags: json.net

this is **not** a dup of [JSON.NET: Deserializing part of a JSON object to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035230/json-net-deserializing-part-of-a-json-object-to-a-dictionary)

I have JSON
    {
      "Count" : 2,
      "Head" : { "itemId":..., "quality":... },
      "Legs" : { "itemId":..., "quality":... }
    }

I need to deserialize it into a dictionary: `IDictionary<GearSlot, Item>`
If I try to deserialize whole JSON I get an error because it fails to deserialize `"Count:2"` into `<GearSlot, Item>`.

`GearSlot` is an enum, and has ~17+ values. At this time I have defined class:

```
public class Items {
    property Item Head { get; set; }
    property Item Legs { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

it works, but not elegant and clunky.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9453198/1037948) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2555899/1037948), you could [deserialize a partial JSON fragment](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm) and then reintegrate.

```
var root = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
var expectedResult = serializer.Deserialize<ExpectedType>(root["fragment"].CreateReader());
```

So for you

```
var items = new Items {
    Head = serializer.Deserialize<Item>(root["Head"])
    , Legs = serializer.Deserialize<Item>(root["Legs"])
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a customer converter. Example: http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/archive/2010/08/26/customizing-the-converter-for-json-net.aspx