# How to Deserialize an JSON object with invalid field name in it

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a JSON request which has follwing structure:

```
"formats":  {
        "flash_embed": "http://a3.vikiassets.com/assets/vikiplayer-922746a667cfd38137a7e45df6ba1b95.swf?auto_play=true&language_codes=en&media_id=74965&partner=16&source=api_v3",
        "m3u8": "http://wpc.354a.edgecastcdn.net/00354A/videos/encoded/74965/ios.m3u8",
        "res-150p": "http://wpc.354a.edgecastcdn.net/00354A/videos/encoded/74965_mp4cell_150.mp4",
        "res-240p": "http://wpc.354a.edgecastcdn.net/00354A/videos/encoded/74965_240p.mp4",
        "res-270p": "http://wpc.354a.edgecastcdn.net/00354A/videos/encoded/74965_270p.mp4",
        "res-360p": "http://wpc.354a.edgecastcdn.net/00354A/videos/encoded/74965_360p.mp4",
        "res-480p": "http://wpc.354a.edgecastcdn.net/00354A/videos/encoded/74965_480p.mp4",
        "res-720p": "http://wpc.354a.edgecastcdn.net/00354A/videos/encoded/74965_720p.mp4"
      }
    }
```

Now res-150p, says invalid name in C# and if I give another name to it then while desiralizing I am not getting any values, that is null inside res-150p.

**Edit:**
[Serializable]
`MoviesListRootObject` is the root Object which Contains `Response` and then `Response` Contains `Formats`

```
public class MoviesListRootObject
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public Pagination pagination { get; set; }
    public List<Response> response { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Response
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int channel_id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string title_language { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string description_language { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
    public string web_uri { get; set; }
    public List<object> genres { get; set; }
    public string origin_country { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public Subtitles subtitles { get; set; }
    public Formats formats { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Formats
{
    public string flash_embed { get; set; }
    public string m3u8 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__res150p { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__res240p { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__res270p { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__res360p { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__res480p { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__res720p { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__flv480p { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__flv360p { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__flv270p { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__flvvp6360p { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__flvvp6270p { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How are you deserializing it?

Comment: Desriliaing with Type , var rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MoviesListRootObject>(json);

Comment: And what's a `MoviesListRootObject`?

Comment: Is this the *exact* data that's failing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to decorate your `Formats` properties with `JsonProperty` attributes to tell it what goes where if the name does not exactly match:

```
partial class Formats
{
    [JsonProperty("res-150p")]
    public string __invalid_name__res150p {get; set;}
}
```

See also [Using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to deserialize Json to a C# POCO class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126242/using-jsonconvert-deserializeobject-to-deserialize-json-to-a-c-sharp-poco-class)

Comment: Thanks, Just curious toknow , Can I also declare normal proporties and have different names using attributes?

Comment: @Simsons Sure. That's what's happening here, right? It just so happens you can't use the same name as the JSON so you *have* to use something new (`__invalid_name__res150p`).