# Deserialize json with numeric key with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I got this json:

```
[
   {
      "name":"Jon",
      "age":"34",
      "24_numeric_key":"somevalue"
   },
   {
      "name":"Mia",
      "age":"26",
      "24_numeric_key":"somevalue"
   },...
]
```

im able to deserialize this with:

```
List<Person> persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
```

but with this i dont get the numeric value. How needs my class person to look like?

class Person:

```
class Person
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string age { get; set; }
   public string _24_numeric_key { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How to Deserialize an JSON object with invalid field name in it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12215181).

Comment: Wow i searched for it and didnt find anything. Thanks bro this sounds promising i will try that

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried renaming you property inside your class to "24_numeric_key"? For proper deserialization the property names must match.

Edit:

People have pointed our a property cannot start with a number, so instead change your JSON data to include the "_" before the number so the property names match again.

Comment: An element name cannot begin with a number.

Comment: Unforutnately i can not change the api response of a thirdparty app :D but if you can that would obviously solve the issue