# One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, dynamic

I work on an windows phone 7.1 app on Visual Studio 2010.
I try to do that:

```
dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
MessageBox.Show(dyn.somevar);
```

I have this error:

> One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?

I tried to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client\Microsof.CSharp.dll` but it doesn't work.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx) keyword requires .Net Framework 4.0. (and DLR).
Windows Phone 7 (and 8) has it's own version of .Net Framework. And dynamic language runtime is not included.

So, you can't use it for Windows Phone development.

Comment: you need to introduce the new type. And deserialize your json into the instance of that type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126242/using-jsonconvert-deserializeobject-to-deserialize-json-to-a-c-sharp-poco-class