# JsonConvert.PopulateObject - Returns empty object

Tags: c#, json

The following bit of code attempts to read some json and populate an object:

```
public Response ParseObject(string Json)
    {


        Response response = new Response();
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(Json, response);
        return response;


    }
```

Here's the Response object:

```
 public class Response
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string incorporationDate { get; set; }
    public string latestAnnualReturnDate { get; set; }
    public string latestAccountsDate { get; set; }
    public string companyType { get; set; }
    public string accountsType { get; set; }
```

Unfortunately, the object (response) is empty ie (response.id is null as are all of the other properties).

I'm guessing that I need to pass in some **JsonSerializerSettings** but I can't find a tutorial anywhere?

Comment: Here a good example how using JsonSerializer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126242/using-jsonconvert-deserializeobject-to-deserialize-json-to-a-c-sharp-poco-class

Comment: It would be very helpfull if you post a json string which doesnt work

Comment: Thanks @danywalls ... just what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your Json string. When I run your code with the below set-up I get the values in the Response object.

```
        var s = "{ \"id\":\"2\" , \"name\":\"Doe\" }";
        Response response = ParseObject(s);
```

Comment: From @danywalls link this was the key:
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var json = wc.DownloadString("http://coderwall.com/mdeiters.json");
    var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
}

Answer (score 0):

Response Try to use the above. This is to get the string from `HttpContext`

```
  Stream dataStream = context.Request.InputStream;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Response  data =(Response )json_serializer.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
```

In your case you can use

```
 JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Response  data =(Response )json_serializer.DeserializeObject(Json);
```