# How to parse that json response?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, restsharp

I am tired about parsing that json response :

I prepared class something for model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Announcements
{
    public class Private
    {
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string updated_at { get; set; }
        public int user_id { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Public
    {
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public User user { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Private> @private { get; set; }
        public List<Public> @public { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now time to deserialize response :

```
            var tempUsersArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Announcements.RootObject>(response.Content);
```

and this makes a app crash...

Anyone have idea what i do wrong?

Comment: Please, provide exception you have

Comment: I've just tested you code and works just fine.

Comment: You might need to decorate your model with `[JsonProperty("<propName>")`. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11126242/2638872

Comment: user3163231, You can be sure for one thing: your problem is not in the code you posted. @mrtig OP's code is fine and works.

Comment: Question doesn't have code which reproduces problem.

Comment: I have that error message :"Attempt to access the method failed: .Announcements+RootObject..ctor()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define permission for class, please chnge `class Announcements` to  `public class Announcements`. Now it should work properly, test this tip please.