# Deserialize Json with no name Fields and Format string, array

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I have the following json object:

```
[
   "sd",
   [
      "sdg\u0026e",
      "sdlc",
      "sdccu",
      "sdsu webportal",
      "sdsu",
      "sdsu blackboard",
      "sdcc",
      "sd card",
      "sdn",
      "sdro"
   ]
]
```

Obtained from google suggest with this URL:

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&hl=en&q=sd

I have tried deserializing it like this:

```
dynamic objson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
```

But it is not useful because I need it into a class object.

And also using types:

```
public class SuggestClass
    {
        public string search { get; set; }
        public string[] terms { get; set; }
    }


var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SuggestClass>(res);
```

But it always throw exception.

I do not know how can I do it without having name fields.

**EDIT:**

Another JSON:

```
["text",["textura","textos bonitos","texto argumentativo","textos","textos de amor","texto expositivo","texturas minecraft","textos de reflexion","texture pack minecraft","textos en ingles"]]
```

Comment: Is that a proper JSON object? because to me, it looks like an array. not an actual object? Anyways, wouldn't it be better to put keys in, obviously your `SuggestClass` has properties, so this means your JSON could have keys, no?

Comment: I obtained it from google. Updated the url source

Comment: It's valid JSON. It's just an array with the second element being an array. You can check it here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: It may not be the perfect answer, but i would just make it into a proper object before parsing it in C#

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126242/using-jsonconvert-deserializeobject-to-deserialize-json-to-a-c-sharp-poco-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's tricky...

But since it's an array, you could create a factory method to parse `SuggestClass` out of given `JArray`.

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    string json =
        "[\"sd\",[\"sdg\u0026e\",\"sdlc\",\"sdccu\"" + 
        ",\"sdsu webportal\",\"sdsu\",\"sdsu blackboard\","+
        "\"sdcc\",\"sd card\",\"sdn\",\"sdro\"]]";

    var factory = new Factory();
    var suggest = factory.Create(json);

    Console.WriteLine(suggest);
}

public class Factory
{
    public SuggestClass Create(string json)
    {
        var array = JArray.Parse(json);
        string search = array[0].ToString();
        string[] terms = array[1].ToArray().Select(item => item.ToString()).ToArray();

        return new SuggestClass {Search = search, Terms = terms};
    }
}

public class SuggestClass
{
    public string Search { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Terms { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Search={0},Terms=[{1}]", 
            Search, string.Join(",", Terms));
    }
}
```

Would print to console:

`Search=sd,Terms=[sdg&e,sdlc,sdccu,sdsu webportal,sdsu,sdsu blackboard,sdcc,sd card,sdn,sdro]`

And the other JSON you provided:

`Search=sd,Terms=[sdg&e,sdlc,sdccu,sdsu webportal,sdsu,sdsu blackboard,sdcc,sd card,sdn,sdro]
Search=text,Terms=[textura,textos bonitos,texto argumentativo,textos,textos de amor,texto expositivo,texturas minecraft,textos de reflexion,texture pack minecraft,textos en ingles]`

Comment: Great approach @Mikko Viitala

Answer (score 0):

Just used the JSON visualizer in visual studio. This is how it looks like.

[image]

It is an array of multiple types. The following code can be used to parse it. But it is not perfect yet.

```
var objson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(res);
```

So I think @Mikko answer has a better approach..