# Deserialize objects from array nested inside Json response

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize some objects nested inside a Json response using Newtonsoft.Json. I want to deserialize the following Jsons `Term` objects into a list. I have many `Term` objects in the Json response, so performance and compactness is important to me. I also would only like to define the `Term` class as I do not care about the other data for the time being.

I have a model defined for Term:

```
public class Term
{
    public string Known { get; set; }
    public string Word { get; set; }
}
```

My Json looks like this:

```
{
    "myName":"Chris",
    "mySpecies":"Cat",
    "myTerms":
    [
        {
            "Term":
            {
                "Known":"true",
                "Word":"Meow"
            }
        },
        {
            "Term":
            {
                "Known":"false",
                "Word":"Bark"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My C# deserializing code:

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetResults();
var searchTermList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Term>>(responseString);
```

The problem/error I'm receiving is, not sure how I can get these terms from the json response:

```
{Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current 
JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CoreProject.Models.Term]' because 
the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or 
change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a 
primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) 
that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be 
added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have a model defined for the other components of this structure? The json you have presented is not a list of terms, it is an object.  You will need to define the higher level object models as well

Comment: Do these answer your questions?  [Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21358493) and [Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”})](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29896264).

Comment: @AaronRoberts is there a way to pull out just the list of `Term`s and deserialize those?

Comment: @visc I would create the object models and then use LINQ to select your list of terms.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting that error because you are trying to deserialize the JSON into a `List<T>` for some `T` (specifically `Term`), but the root JSON container is not an array, it is an object -- an unordered set of key/value pairs surrounded by `{` and `}` -- that contains a fairly deeply embedded collection of objects corresponding to your `Term`.

Given that, you could use http://json2csharp.com/ or [Paste JSON as Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526659/how-to-show-the-paste-json-class-in-visual-studio-2012-when-clicking-on-paste) to auto-generate a complete data model corresponding to your JSON, then deserialize to that model and select out the interesting portions.

If, however, you don't want to define a complete data model, you can selectively deserialize only the relevant portions by loading your JSON into an intermediate [`JToken` hierarchy](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) and then using 
[`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm):

```
var root = JToken.Parse(responseString);
var searchTermList = root.SelectTokens("myTerms[*].Term")
    .Select(t => t.ToObject<Term>())
    .ToList();
```

Notes:

- The query string `"myTerms[*].Term"` contains the [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) wildcard operator `[*]`.  This operator matches all array elements under the parent element `"myTerms"`.

  Json.NET supports JSONPath syntax as documented in [Querying JSON with JSONPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm).
- If the JSON is more complex than is shown in your question, you can use the JSONPath recursive descent operator `...` instead to find `Term` objects at any level in the JSON object hierarchy, e.g.:

  ```
  var searchTermList = root.SelectTokens("..Term")
      .Select(t => t.ToObject<Term>())
      .ToList();
  ```
- Once the relevant JSON objects have been selected you can use [`Jtoken.ToObject<Term>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm) to deserialize each one to your final c# model.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kNX6CD).

Comment: +one Didn't know about using jsonpath. Nice idea !

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
public class Term
{
    public string Known { get; set; }
    public string Word { get; set; }
}
public class Response
{
    public List<TermWrapper> MyTerms { get; set; }
}
public class TermWrapper
{
    public Term Term { get; set; }
}

...

var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetResults();
var searchTermList = JsonConvert
    .DeserializeObject<Response>(responseString)
    .MyTerms
    .Select(x => x.Term);
```

You have to consider the full structure of the JSON.  You have an object with 3 properties.  The one you are interested in is an Array of Objects, but the objects are not terms, they are objects with a property called "Term".  That property itself is of type `Term`.  By creating the classes with similar structure you can then pull all the necessary data out of the structure.