# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object"

Tags: c#, json

This is my JSON file

```
{
    "id": "5f5643b34ae3b73a74622a20",
    "checkItemStates": [],
    "closed": false,
    "dateLastActivity": "2020-09-07T15:13:27.924Z",
    "desc": "",
    "descData": null,
    "dueReminder": null,
    "idBoard": "5f56231449e3e149cd81f345",
    "idList": "5f554014d13fa38a52274132",
    "idMembersVoted": [],
    "idShort": 2,
    "idAttachmentCover": null,
    "idLabels": [],
    "manualCoverAttachment": false,
    "name": "Hello World",
    "pos": 16384,
    "shortLink": "aqz6ee6J",
    "isTemplate": false,
    "dueComplete": false,
    "due": null,
    "email": null,
    "labels": [],
    "shortUrl": "https://trello.com/c/aqz6ee6J",
    "start": null,
    "url": "https://trello.com/c/aqz6ee6J/2-hello-world",
    "cover": {
        "idAttachment": null,
        "color": null,
        "idUploadedBackground": null,
        "size": "normal",
        "brightness": "light"
    },
    "idMembers": [
        "5b615a281019e549117835fd"
    ],
    "idChecklists": [],
    "badges": {
        "attachmentsByType": {
            "trello": {
                "board": 0,
                "card": 0
            }
        },
        "location": false,
        "votes": 0,
        "viewingMemberVoted": false,
        "subscribed": true,
        "fogbugz": "",
        "checkItems": 0,
        "checkItemsChecked": 0,
        "checkItemsEarliestDue": null,
        "comments": 0,
        "attachments": 0,
        "description": false,
        "due": null,
        "dueComplete": false,
        "start": null
    },
    "subscribed": true
}
```

this is my class

```
    public class Card
    {
        public class CardDetails
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<object> CheckItemStates { get; set; }
            public bool Closed { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateLastActivity { get; set; }
            public string Desc { get; set; }
            public object DescData { get; set; }
            public object DueReminder { get; set; }
            public string IdBoard { get; set; }
            public string IdList { get; set; }
            public List<object> IdMembersVoted { get; set; }
            public int IdShort { get; set; }
            public object IdAttachmentCover { get; set; }
            public List<object> IdLabels { get; set; }
            public bool ManualCoverAttachment { get; set; }
            public int Oos { get; set; }
            public string ShortLink { get; set; }
            public bool IsTemplate { get; set; }
            public bool DueComplete { get; set; }
            public object Due { get; set; }
            public object Email { get; set; }
            public List<object> Labels { get; set; }
            public string ShortUrl { get; set; }
            public object Start { get; set; }
            public string Url { get; set; }
            public Cover Cover { get; set; }
            public List<string> IdMembers { get; set; }
            public List<object> IdChecklists { get; set; }
            public Badges Badges { get; set; }
            public bool Subscribed { get; set; }
        }


        public class Cover
        {
            public object IdAttachment { get; set; }
            public object Color { get; set; }
            public object IdUploadedBackground { get; set; }
            public string Size { get; set; }
            public string Brightness { get; set; }
        }

        public class Trello
        {
            public int Board { get; set; }
            public int Card { get; set; }
        }

        public class AttachmentsByType
        {
            public Trello Trello { get; set; }
        }

        public class Badges
        {
            public AttachmentsByType AttachmentsByType { get; set; }
            public bool Location { get; set; }
            public int Votes { get; set; }
            public bool ViewingMemberVoted { get; set; }
            public bool Subscribed { get; set; }
            public string Fogbugz { get; set; }
            public int CheckItems { get; set; }
            public int CheckItemsChecked { get; set; }
            public object CheckItemsEarliestDue { get; set; }
            public int Comments { get; set; }
            public int Attachments { get; set; }
            public bool Description { get; set; }
            public object Due { get; set; }
            public bool DueComplete { get; set; }
            public object Start { get; set; }
        }
}
```

the last but not least, this my request implementation

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        public async Task<List<Card>> GetApiData()
        {
            var uri = new Uri("https://api.trello.com/1/cards/.......");
            HttpResponseMessage respone = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            respone.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            var content = await respone.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Card>>(content);
            return json;
        }
```

**I am always getting the following error no matter what:**

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LeanVoting.Trello.Card]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
> Path 'id', line 1, position 6.

The steps I have already taken are:

1. Remove attributes that I don't need (make it shorter)
2. According to the error, I have also remove datatype like int, collection List<>, objects as well as boolean.
3. Change them all to string

So, unfortunately, it's still not working and I can't figure out the reason anymore.

It would be a big pleaser if some could help me with.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The error is quite clear; you're trying to take a piece of JSON representing a single object (i.e., that begins with `{`) and trying the deserialize to a List, which requires multiple objects in an array (i.e., the JSON must begin with `[`).

Comment: In your case, your JSON doesn't represent a list of `Card`s, it represents a single `Card`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896264/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object-e-g-namevalue)

Comment: Did my answer help? The other classes looked good, you should `Deserialize` into the class that I posted.