# How to convert an irregular JSON to dictionary or object?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I know hot to Deserialize JSONs like `{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}`

But now I am trying to use instagram API and it returns me a Json in this form

```
{
    "access_token": "fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d",
    "user": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "..."
    }
}
```

Since it is not structured like an array of keys and values I am confused.
I need to assign those values to the following class of mine.

```
public class AccessTokenResult
        {
            public string AccessTokenString { get; set; }

            public class UserWhoTook
            {
                public int ID { get; set; }
                public string UserName { get; set; }
                public string FullName { get; set; }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reccomend you use http://json2csharp.com/ to format your Objects. Just paste in the json and it should spit out the classes for you.

For example, the json you posted generated.

```
public class User
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string profile_picture { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [JsonConvert](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) and questions like [Using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to deserialize Json to a C# POCO class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126242/using-jsonconvert-deserializeobject-to-deserialize-json-to-a-c-sharp-poco-class)

Comment: I am upvoting it because I also had a problem to build the structure. But this was helpful, and really clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party libraries for JSON, for example Newton Json.net: https://json.codeplex.com/