# cannot bind data to a listpicker, obtained from a json string in xaml for windows phone8 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, windows-phone-8

when I bind data to the listpicker, I get name displayed in selected item, but when the dropdown shows the whole item will be myProject.MyClass....something
I am new to windows phone application development.. Can anyone help me with this?

here is my xaml code

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Header="Select Name" Name="listName" Tap="listName_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate> 
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Here is my c# code

```
class MyClass
{
    public String name{ get; set; }
}

private void sendPostCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)     
{
    //e.result is my json string obtained from webservice([{name:hhh}{name:jkj}{name:jack}])
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass[]>(e.Result.ToString()); 
    listName.ItemsSource = data;
}
```

Comment: here is the xaml code                                                     <toolkit:ListPicker Header="Select Client"   Name="listName VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                           </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                       
                    </toolkit:ListPicker>

Comment: Please attach a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure but I think the problem is with the binding. You're binding an `Array`, instead of it try `List`:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(e.Result.ToString());
```

You also need to add `JsonProperty` to your class property ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126242/using-jsonconvert-deserializeobject-to-deserialize-json-to-a-c-sharp-poco-class)):

```
class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public String name{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: hi sorry fore the delay in reply.. actually the problem was with setting a full mode item template. i didnt set fullmodeitem template before.. anyway thanks for your reply..

Comment: @shahna It would be great if you answer your own question and accept it. It will help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code :

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Header="Select Name" Name="listName" Tap="listName_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource={Binding NamesList}>
   <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate> 
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

In Code behind, Add the following :

```
private ObservableCollection<MyClass> _NamesList = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();    
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> NamesList 
{ 
   get {return _NamesList} 
   set {_NamesList = value}
}
```

Add below code in constructor

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Copy the array data to observablecollection

```
private void sendPostCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)     
    {
        //e.result is my json string obtained from webservice([{name:hhh}{name:jkj}{name:jack}])
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass[]>(e.Result.ToString()); 

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                NamesList.Items.Add(item);
            }
    }
```

Note : Use ObservableCollection for binding list UI controls for updating UI data while property changes.

Comment: hi, it shows an error like,                                                                                  Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<MyProject.Views.MyClass>' is less accessible than property 'MyProject.Views.ViewNames.NamesList'

Comment: Make your MyClass Public ... 
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public String name{ get; set; }
}

Comment: hi sorry fore the delay in reply.. actually the problem was with setting a full mode item template. i didnt set fullmodeitem template before.. anyway thanks for your reply..