# JSON.net filter repositories received from website

Tags: c#, json.net, restsharp

Hello Stackoverflow Community,
I recently got into C# and JSON.net and my task is to filter the repositories I receive from a website. I am working with the Crucible API.

```
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(User, Password);
var request = new RestRequest("", Method.GET);
Console.Clear();

client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
});

Console.Read();
```

How would i filter out everything besides the displayNames of the repositories i recieve in my console application? The current output looks like this:

```
{
    "repoData": [{
            "name": "Example",
            "displayName": "Example",
            "type": "git",
            "enabled": true,
            "available": true,
            "location": "Example.com",
            "path": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: your json is not valid, try to add valid json. bcoz your array and outer curly brace not closed

Comment: "How would i filter out the displayNames of the repositories i recieve in my console application?" -> you mean you want to display the JSOn but without the name/displayName properties?

Comment: Sorry @John i formulated the question wrong; I only want to display the DisplayName properties. I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: 1) Deserialize the JSON to C# classes. 2) Use LINQ's `.Select` on the list of repositories to extract only the name field. - Basically, look at the links ManishM provided, and if you get update your question showing how far you got.

Comment: @Hollowpoint, does your json contains only single object in your array?

Comment: @ershoaib No it contains a lot of objects, I just put this single one as an example for better readability.

Comment: @Hollowpoint, so you have to read displayName for only first object or all from lot of objects

Comment: @ershoaib from all objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a quick type for your json

```
public class RepoData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public bool enabled { get; set; }
    public bool available { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject4
{
    public List<RepoData> repoData { get; set; }
}
```

Here i create an console app for your demonstration purpose

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = @"{'repoData':[{'name':'Example','displayName':'Example1','type':'git','enabled':true,'available':true,'location':'Example.com','path':''}, {'name':'Example','displayName':'Example2','type':'git','enabled':true,'available':true,'location':'Example.com','path':''}]}";

        RootObject4 rootObject4 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject4>(json);

        List<string> displayNames = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in rootObject4.repoData)
        {
            displayNames.Add(item.displayName);
        }

        displayNames.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

---

**Alternative:** If you don't want to create any classes then `JObject` will better handle your json and you will extract `displayName` values by below code sample console app.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = @"{'repoData':[{'name':'Example','displayName':'Example1','type':'git','enabled':true,'available':true,'location':'Example.com','path':''}, {'name':'Example','displayName':'Example2','type':'git','enabled':true,'available':true,'location':'Example.com','path':''}]}";

        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

        var repoData = jObject["repoData"];

        var displayNames = repoData.Select(x => x["displayName"]).Values().ToList();

        displayNames.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: @Hollowpoint, also view **Alternative** section in answer might be it help you :) and let me know

Comment: @Hollowpoint, in above code `var json`  is your `response.Content`

Comment: I understand all the logic behind this, but it won't let me parse response, because it can't convert to a string

Comment: i got it now, i had to parse response.content, thanks a 1000 times. I would hug you if I could :D

Comment: Glad to hear, If my answer help you then please mark tick beside the answer to make it green :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. Example is given below

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

[Using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to deserialize Json to a C# POCO class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126242/using-jsonconvert-deserializeobject-to-deserialize-json-to-a-c-sharp-poco-class)

By the way, your JSON is incomplete. Please add the complete output so others can help better.