# I need to access a JSON object inside another object or ArrayList via using dynamic. How can I access JSON objects using dynamic?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my code.

```
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
    double value = obj.Price;
```

and here is my JSON data, I am trying grab the value that is inside Price. How would I access the value inside Price or even TotalPrice???

```
{
    "Order": [
        {
            "Number": "1",
            "Price": 1.99
        }
    ],
    "TotalPrice": 1.99
}
```

Please, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net

Comment: [Using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to deserialize Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126242/), [Deserialize Json object into dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/), many others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to 'select' your object from array named Order (using index), then its property:

```
double value = obj.Order[0].Price;
```