# Json.Net deserialize anonymous type

Tags: asp.net, json, serialization, anonymous-types, json.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deserializing JSON into an object with Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555363/deserializing-json-into-an-object-with-json-net)

Any ideas of how to deserialize the following response into anonymous type using Json.Net?

```
{"d":[{"day":"Wednesday","firstSet":{"start":"17:00","close":"23:00","hours":6,"isValid":true},"secondSet":{"start":"00:00","close":"00:00","hours":0,"isValid":false},"personMinimum":2,"personMaximum":25}]}
```

Attempts so far result in the following error

Could not cast or convert from System.String to <>f__AnonymousType3`5[System.String,<>f__AnonymousType2`4[System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.Boolean],<>f__AnonymousType2`4[System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.Boolean],System.Int32,System.Int32].

Code is supplied below

```
var json_complex = new
{
  d = new
  {
    day = "",
    firstSet = new
    {
      start = "",
      close = "",
      hours = 0,
      isValid = false
    },
    secondSet = new
    {
      start = "",
      close = "",
      hours = 0,
      isValid = false
    },
    personMinimum = 2,
    personMaximum = 25
  }
};
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonResponse, json_complex);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See stackoverflow [post][1] about deserializing JSON into an object with Json.NET for the answer

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555363/deserializing-json-into-an-object-with-json-net/2555899#2555899

Answer (score -10, accepted):

First of all I must say why are you including third party into your application ?

Asp.net provides `JavaScriptSerializer` for serialization !

Look at my question and refer the answer you can get idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9112167/1162201)

Comment: It can be because Json.net is more convenient and flexible than JavaScriptSerializer. E.g. Json.net has a linq-2-json feature which allows you to build Json object "on the fly" and query Json objects using linq syntax.

Comment: "Why are you including third party into your application ?" - Why are you against using awesome opensource code?

Comment: Don't use JavaScriptSerializer. Use Newtonsoft.Json. Even Microsoft use it rather than their own System.Json. JavaScriptSerializer has a lot of problems that Newtonsoft will overcome. Plus Newtonsoft is faster.